# Angular CanActivate with Firebase Backend

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm developing an Angular app with a Firebase backend. On launch the app needs to check to see if the user is currently signed in; if the user is logged in the app should navigate to the home page, if the user is not logged in the app should navigate to the log in page.

I'd like to achieve this using a single `canActivate` `AuthGuard` on the `Home` route definition, i.e.,

```
const homeRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
]
```

where `AuthGuard` implements `canActivate` as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  canActivate() {
    // Need to work out what goes here
  }
}
```

Now Firebase provides the observable `onAuthStateChanged` (see [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users)) that I can use to determine if a user is currently logged in, and given that`canActivate` can return a boolean observable, I could write my `AuthGuard` as follows

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

  constructor(private firebaseService: Firebase, private router: Router){}

  canActivate() {

      return Observable.create(obs => {
          this.firebaseService.onAuthStateChanged(user => {
              if (user) {
                 obs.next(true);
              }
              else {
                 obs.next(false);
                 router.navigate(['login']);
              }
          });
   }
}
```

This seems to work when I launch the app having not logged in, i.e., I'm directed to the login page. However, now when I successfully log in the app attempts to navigate to `home`, calls `canActivate` on the `AuthGuard` but appears to stall at this point, i.e., I remain on the login page. I presume this is because I'm returning an observable and the state has already changed before `canActivate` is called, so nothing tells `canActivate` that it can show the `home` page.

Is there a clean way to deal with the situation where I need `canActivate` to return an observable when starting up to ensure that Firebase has initialised before I determine whether they are already signed in, but then have `canActivate` return a boolean once everything is initialised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I switched to AngularFire2 which makes this easier:

```
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.af.authState.map(auth => {
      if (isNullOrUndefined(auth)) {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

[Check this out](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2)

**EDIT**

An other option is to use `bindCallback` to create an observable from the callback and perform a map just like my example.

Comment: Not keen to have additional dependencies but looks like your link to AngularFire2 could lead to a solution, i.e., looks like the af source uses [observeOn](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/observeon.html) so I probably need to understand and implement this, Will update after a deeper look.

Comment: Yes, works when providing a zone scheduler as in angular fire 2.